# Android Studio Error:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio

Today I bought a new laptop with Ubuntu and when I tried to open my android project from my old laptop I got

> Error:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory).

So I checked the directory and I have the file so I don't know what to do. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

That's an issue due to the installation of java on your machine.

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts is a symlink to /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

That file is generated by a post install script. IIRC the package is openjdk-7-jre-headless but I may be wrong.

Btw the script runs
sudo update-ca-certificates
and that generates the cacerts file.

So long story short, run sudo update-ca-certificates to generate the file and then you will manage to sync the grandle files with the project.